# Shell script called from Java is not exiting

Tags: java, shell, unix

I am calling a shell script from Java and reading it's response back..this works fine..but for one of my script where I run a particular process in background the script never ends and everything remains still.please help me to resolve this.
//script

```
run(){
 //starts a process in background
 return 0;
}
if [ "$ACTION" = "install" ]
then
  run
  exit 0;
fi
```

Comment: Are you [reading from the streams](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html)? You need to do this in separate threads so that the buffers don't become full. I would consider using a process management library such as [zt exec](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec) to handle the complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes,I am using stream for readin..But that doesn't overloads..because that is the only script I am calling